Consolidate Sewer Vents
I currently have 2 separate roof penetrations for sewer venting. From the roof, they’re 3” and I’d like to eliminate one if possible. The penetrations are probably 15ft apart.
One vent is for the main bathroom (Vent A). One vent is for the master bathroom (Vent B). I’m thinking I could reroute the 2” from the main bath (Vent A), to tie into Vent B. I’m unable to tie the 3” into the existing 3” due to obstructions.
Any reason why I can’t tie them together in the attic? Any negative impact to performance or additional things to consider? It just seems like maybe the contractor was being lazy…



You're 100% sure they're sewer vents, and not some kind of fan vent?

@Huesmann Yes, my fan vents were dumping into the attic…that was a recent project I resolved too.

Depending on climate, making sure they don't freeze up with the near-horizontal run across the attic (can be as simple as "that's done close to the ceiling with plenty of insulation over it") and making sure that the run is, in fact, sloped to drain properly to the drain it serves, not actually horizontal.
Also making sure the main vent is large enough to handle all the fixtures, but that's fairly likely with a 3" stack.
The 1-1/2" vent pipes should both have a Tee with a cleanout on top, rather than an elbow. The 2" vent should have a cross with a cleanout on top rather than a Tee. You can snake the 2" directly under the 3" from the roof - you can't expect to get a snake from the roof into the other 3 vertical pipes.

Would adding a 45 on the roof, to reduce the potential for snow/water entering the vent be worthwhile? That may help to eliminate your point about water freezing in the attic space. Only water in the pipes in the attic would be from snow/rain entering from roof.

Vent pipes are typically covered with condensate (which comes from water vapor from the drain pipes they serve) on the inside. That's how vents in cold attic spaces freeze up. The contributions of snow and rain are trivial, and most plumbing codes prefer a straight pipe open to the sky.
